# prime number Result in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am newbie I wrote a prime number program which takes user input and print all prime numbers till user input number and result will be display in gridview. program is correct but i am facing difficulties to display all prime numbers in gridview.so should I use datatable? here is the prime number code:-

```
int a = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text);
            int i, j;
            for (i = 2; i <= a; i++)
            {
                for (j = 2; j < i; j++)
                {
                    if (i % j == 0)
                        break;
                }
                if (i == j)
                {
                    Response.Write(i + "is a prime number" + "</br>");
                }
            }
```

Comment: Create a list and add the items in there and databind the list to the gridview, you can use [List<integer>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) for example.

Comment: thank you very much it helped me